# why we are using dot/arrow operator to access structure variables in c

Tags: c, structure

I dont kno why we are using this to access variables. Is there any standards ? if there what are they ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct st {
  int i;
  char ch;
} s;
int main() {
  s.i = 10;
  printf("%d\n", s.i);
}
```

Comment: Because that's how the language is designed.  The standard is the [C Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard).

Comment: thank you Robert Harvey. Previously i forgot to check in standard library

Comment: It is not a matter of "standard library": it is the language; and not only C uses the dot for accessing members. In regard to the arrow, a character would have be chosen, but perhaps they ran out of them... anyway the arrow is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

The dot operator and the arrow operator are not the same:

The dot operator takes the attribute of a structure.
The arrow operator takes the attribute of the structure, the pointer you are using refers to.

Answer (score 0):

```
These two lines are the same thing:
(*(*(*a).b).c).d

a->b->c->d
```

It just seems more practical and better to look at, otherwise you'd have to use the one at the top which seems very hard to read, so we use the -> operator because it's much simpler.

Comment: my doubt is why we have to use dot/arrow operator to access the value of a variable

Comment: @UssrSankar read something about structures. If you understand why they are useful, you will understand many more things.

Comment: because a structure is much like a type like an (int, double, float) that means when you create a struct and have 2 values like int number; char letter; the computer doesn't allocate memory to those 2 value unless you create an instance of the struct, and allocate memory for those values.